# Custom Zone Theming

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am building out an Orchard site with a theme that was built by a graphic artist who knows nothing about Orchard. Plugging that in is fairly simple, however the way he built it offered some various various options to the end user that I'm trying to replicate, preferably without building a custom module. The way he built the template is he included four different layout types: a 50/50, 33/67, 67/33 and a 100% (this one works because of Model.Content).

Sample Graphical View:

```
50/50
=================================================================================
|                                         |                                     |
|  <Left bar with HTML content>           |  <Right bar with HTML content>      |
|                                         |                                     |
=================================================================================

33/67
=================================================================================
|                       |                                                       |
| <Small Left w/HTML>   |  <Large Right w/HTML>                                 |
|                       |                                                       |
=================================================================================
```

(and so on..)

Based on what I can tell, there are ways to create various content types within Orchard that have a "Body" option (so I can have an HTML editor), but I can't figure out how to create one of these with two HTML editors on it so I can have a single routable page that has two zones it can affect. Inside Layout.cshtml, my example of binding a two-column layout would be like this:

```
@if (Model.SplitLeft != null && Model.SplitRight != null) {
    @* 50/50 split view *@
    <div class="col_12">
        <div class="col_6 clearleft padding_top_15">
            @Zone(Model.SplitLeft)
        </div>
        <div class="col_6 omega">
            @Zone(Model.SplitRight)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I know widgets have the capability to specify zones, but I'm trying to avoid those because they don't make it intuitive to an end-user when trying to build a two-column layout that they need to add two widgets, apply them to specific zones on specific layers, modify layer rules, etc. The site will have 40-50 pages that can be any of the four types specified above, so managing that via layers/widgets would be very complex. Further, it also doesn't allow the publish/unpublish model that I guarantee my client would want.

I can certainly build a module to do this if I need to, but something tells me Orchard already supports this and I'm just missing something in how to set it up.

Suggestions?

**Edit:** I looked into utilizing Alternates a bit, but I couldn't figure out how to create a content type that would have two other types underneath it (i.e. left/right views for the HTML editor). Probably the biggest hurdle is that I need two HTML editors to show up on the main editing screen so it's obvious to the user which is which (i.e. SmallLeft/LargeRight, LargeLeft/SmallRight, 50/50 Split) so building the page is intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add additional HTML editors, you need to add `TextField` to your content item. After you've added it, you need to set `html` as the `flavour` of that field.

Comment: That worked, but how do I specify which zones on the Model those go into? I tried placement.info, but no luck. The content type I created was called "SplitPage" (that was the content ID) and my XML for the placement file was:

<Match ContentType="SplitPage">
  <Place Parts_Title="-"/>
  <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
  <Place Parts_Fields_Common_Text-LeftSide="SplitLeft" />
  <Place Parts_Fields_Common_Text-RightSide="SplitRight" />
</Match>

This match request was partially honored (metadata disappeared), but pushing my two text fields into those zones on the model didn't work.

Comment: Actually, it's not `Parts_Fields_Common_Text-LeftSide` but rather `Fields_Common_Text-LeftSide` (without `Parts_`). You must note that this will match local zones (zones inside your `Content-SplitPage.cshtml` template shown by `@Display(Model.SplitLeft)`). If you need to place in the global zones (inside `Layout.cshtml` template)  you need to place `/` sign before the zone name (for example: `<Place Fields_Common_Text-LeftSide="/SplitLeft" />`)

Comment: Perfect! That did exactly what I needed, minus one other thing. The content now shows up as expected, but the name of each text field (i.e. Left Side: [html content from editor]) is showing up before the text from the CMS editor. I'm sure removing that is also a placement.info configuration entry, but I'm not certain how to accomplish it.

Comment: Text fields by default implement template `/Core/Common/Views/Fields.Common.Text.cshtml`. It renders as `FieldName: HtmlContent`. You should copy this file to your theme's `Views` folder and change it to suit your needs..

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to copy in Fields.Common.Text.cshtml from Orchard.Core into my theme and modify it there.

Comment: Almost at the same time :)